# Smooth css marquee

Tags: css

I have a CSS marquee, and it runs good, but is not 100% smooth. 
Can I edit the code below to run more smooth?

I have tried different animation: marquee Xs linear infinite speeds, but no luck.

```
<style>
/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #000000;
bottom: 0px;
}

.marquee span {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 100%;
text-indent: 0;
animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
bottom: 0px;
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

/* Make it pretty */
.scroll {
padding-left: 1.5em;
position: fixed;
font: 50px 'Verdana';
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 10%;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="scroll marquee"><span id="scrolltext"></span></p>
```

Comment: What is your html? Please include an example.

Comment: maybe <div class="marquee"><span>Lorem ipsum</span></div>? :)

Comment: @CalvT. HTML added

Answer (score 1):

add id="marquee" to your span. remove the animation line from css and add this javascript at the end of your code:

```
var marqueePosition = 0;
var speed = 10; //smaller number means faster movement
var e = document.getElementById('marquee');
function moveMarquee() {
    marqueePosition--;
    if(marqueePosition < (-1*e.offsetWidth)) marqueePosition = 0;
    e.style["-webkit-transform"] = "translate("+marqueePosition+"px, 0px)";
    e.style["-moz-transform"] = "translate("+marqueePosition+"px, 0px)";
    e.style["-ms-transform"] = "translate("+marqueePosition+"px, 0px)";
    e.style["-o-transform"] = "translate("+marqueePosition+"px, 0px)";
    e.style["transform"] = "translate("+marqueePosition+"px, 0px)";
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(moveMarquee);
    }, speed);
}
moveMarquee();
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because of a long time setted in animation. you need to change the time to make it smoother. but it depends on the width of the marquee too. I suggest to you using the javascript to do this.

if you set that it should ride for example 200px in 10 seconds it cant be smooth as there is a small framerate :D in JS you can set the speed independently on the marquee width

Comment: Do you have a sample script of Java that can do this?

Comment: see my another answer